# Groovy Null-Pointer Riddle :-)

Tags: groovy

This is more a riddle than a question since I already know the answer, but I thought that maybe some other devs might enjoy this :-)

Imagine you need to put a string like to following apart:

```
def line = "path /some/path/to/somewhere/test.txt"
```

and you want to get only the file name. Somehow you start with code like this:

```
println line-"path "
==> /some/path/to/somewhere/test.txt
```

works great - let's split the remaining part:

```
println (line-"path ").split("/")
```

but now you get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method split() on null object
```

you've seen before that `line-"path "` is not null, so you give it another try

```
def temp = line-"path "
println temp.split("/")
==> [, some, path, to, somewhere, test.txt]
```

that works! What's going on?

Are you able to avoid the `temp`-variable and write the above statement as one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's `println((line-"path ").split("/"))`.  Otherwise you will attempt to split the result of println, which is nil.

Comment: @rdmueller if this was actually intended as a riddle, maybe it would be a better fit for the puzzle section of stackexchange.  your failing code there is actually already part of the infamous groovy puzzlers. so bascially this is me objecting, you putting my answer in a spoiler tag. SO is a QA page after all.

Comment: you are right. But this problem took me long to solve (since the workaround is trivial, I never tried to find out why my one-liner failed) and that's the reason why I posted it on SO and not codegolf :-) Feel free to to move it.

Answer (score 1):

Works good for me. No NullPointerException:

```
def line = "path /some/path/to/somewhere/test.txt"
def temp = line-"path "
println temp.split("/")
```

Your one-liner would be:

> `println ((line-"path ").split("/"))` OR `line.split(" ")[1].split("/")​​​`